# Using highlight.js CDN

Tags: html, syntax-highlighting, cdn, highlight.js

I can't seem to get syntax highlighting to work with highlight.js. Here's a test example:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.5.0/styles/default.min.css">
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.5.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
    <script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
    <title>Test Highlight</title>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <pre>
        <code class="language-python">
          def f(x, y):
            return x + y
        </code>
    </pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

I included the CSS and JS CDNs and called `hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad()`, yet code still shows up entirely in black text:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a typo in your link and script tag URL.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.5.0/styles/default.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.5.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.5.0/styles/default.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.5.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
    <script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
    <title>Test Highlight</title>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <pre>
        <code class="language-python">
          def f(x, y):
            return x + y
        </code>
    </pre>
  </body>
</html>
```